# Awk formatted output how to include sign for floats

Tags: awk

I want to reformat a file by adjusting the spacing between fields. I have the managed to get the content into this form:

```
  130GLU    HB2  383   0.058   5.178   2.925
  130GLU     CG  384   -0.108   5.065   2.887
  130GLU    HG1  385   -0.079   5.007   2.963
```

What I can't get right is the floats with minus signs. The above formatting is produced by `awk '{printf "  %6s%7s%5s   %5.3f   %5.3f   %5.3f\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}' file`. However, I want to get the following:

```
  130GLU    HB2  383   0.058   5.178   2.925
  130GLU     CG  384  -0.108   5.065   2.887
  130GLU    HG1  385  -0.079   5.007   2.963
```

In other words, account for the sign in counting the characters of the number, in this case the `5` part of `%5.3f`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a simple change - see if it works:

```
awk '{printf "  %6s%7s%5s   % 5.3f   % 5.3f   % 5.3f\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}' file
Result:
  130GLU    HB2  383    0.058    5.178    2.925
  130GLU     CG  384   -0.108    5.065    2.887
  130GLU    HG1  385   -0.079    5.007    2.963
```

or

```
awk '{printf "  %6s%7s%5s   %+5.3f   %+5.3f   %+5.3f\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}'
Result:
  130GLU    HB2  383   +0.058   5.178   2.925
  130GLU     CG  384   -0.108   5.065   2.887
  130GLU    HG1  385   -0.079   5.007   2.963
```

Edit:

```
awk '{printf "  %6s%7s%5s  % 5.3f  % 5.3f  % 5.3f\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}' file
Result:
  130GLU    HB2  383   0.058   5.178   2.925
  130GLU     CG  384  -0.108   5.065   2.887
  130GLU    HG1  385  -0.079   5.007   2.963
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need the number of spaces to remain as 3 minus the sign character. And I also need the `+` not to appear at all.

Comment: @melpomene well it has 3 blanks and the minus sign. It needs to be either 3 blanks, or 2 blanks and minus sign.

Comment: Edited my answer. For example, in the first line, after 383 there are 3 blanks before 0.058. In second line, after 384 there are 2 blanks then a minus and then 0.108. Is that what you want?